# How to Edit PDF programatically with Open Office PDF Import Extension

Tags: c#, openoffice.org

I want to edit the PDF text layer programatically through the Open Office PDF Import Extension.

I know it is possible to edit the PDF file through OPEN OFFICE PDF file extension from the Open Office UI.

Is there any API available for .Net of PDF Import Extension to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason for using OpenOffice.org for this?  You can manipulate pdf files in the way you want using [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

Comment: I have OCRed Image over text PDF files. I tried with ItextSharp but I did not find the edit option for existing pdf docs. however, you can add new text. Does it provide search and replace funcationality? and after editing the PDF file with iTextSharp will it retain the existing quality of the PDF and keep it searchable.